# batch script to delete all icons from all users' desktops

Tags: batch-file

Currently looking for a way to delete all icons off of all user desktops. I have experimented until I made the following script that allowed me to delete all from a single user but without hard coding I won't be able to extend this to reach all users on a single PC.

```
@echo off
cd %%#
del C:\Users\%Userprofile%\Desktop\*.* /s /q
for /r %%# in (.) do rmdir %%# /s
cls
```

I am now looking to see if it is possible to extend this to multiple users without hard coding paths since I don't happen to know which user might be using the computer at the time.

Comment: Please clarify what your intention is, your code appears to delete all files and remove all directories from a users desktop, which has nothing to do with icons.

Comment: Sorry I was misleading with my post I am meaning to completely empty the folder including the directories.

Comment: All you need to do is to code something which retrieves a listing of users according to your specifications and then run the command against each of the users in the list, probably within a `For` loop. Enter `For /?` at the command prompt to read its usage information. _Don't forget about the All Users/Public Desktops too!_

Comment: The code in your question is invalid. In `del C:\Users\%Userprofile%\Desktop\*.* /s /q` the path `C:\Users\%Userprofile%\Desktop\*.*` is not valid it should be `%Userprofile%\Desktop\*.*`. You have used `%%#` in `cd %%#` ouside of the `FOR loop`. I suppose it was meant be `cd "%Userprofile%\Desktop"`. with that assumption it is still a dangerous code: `for /r %%# in (.) do rmdir %%# /s` , you should first make sure that the `cd` command have succeeded before attempting to remove files or folders from current directory otherwise you may end up removing files from the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to hard code path's, we can use the `FOR` to search for `.ico` files located in `\Desktop` for each user. The script bellow will search each users desktop, remove all .ico files, then prompt the user it has finished.

```
@ECHO OFF
@GOTO :search

:search
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\desktop\*.ico" (
    set correctDir=%%G\desktop
    goto :foundFile
)
goto :finished

:foundFile
cd "%correctDir%"
del /S *.ico
goto :search

:finished
echo All Icons removed from users desktops!
pause
goto :eof
```

`FOR /D` iterates over all directories using the `%%G` variable. `%%~fG` expands to the full path to the directory in %%G.
`IF EXIST` checks if a file exists.
`goto :eof` exits the script

Comment: You must pardon me, I was signed in to my other account haha. I rather post it on this account.

Comment: Long story short, I got a new computer one day and the google login I used was for a different email. This site went ahead and created the new account.

Comment: Iterating all of the top level directories within `C:\Users` is not a recommended way of generating the users to cycle through.

Comment: This was very helpful I ended up inserting my script into the found file function and am waiting for a chance to test it.

Comment: Looping through `C:\Users\*` might work in many cases, but remember that you could store a user's profile also at a totally different location; I guess you had to query the registry to retrieve all users' Desktop folders...

Comment: @aschipfl I based this code off the OP's provided code. Looks like the user's profiles are only being stored/targeted in the `C:\Users\*`.

Answer (score 0):

Extreme care must be taken when writing or working with scripts which are intended to delete files/folders. A single minor mistake can end up in a disaster.

For example this code: `cd "MyFolder" & del /q *.*` is extremely dangerous it delete all files from current directory with the assumption that previous `cd` command have changed the current directory to `MyFolder`, So in case of failure `del` command will delete all files from current directory which is not `MyFolder`. But this code is safe: `cd "MyFolder" && del /q *.*`. The `del` command will be executed only if the `cd` command have successfully changed the current directory to `MyFolder`.

Now back to your original problem of extending your code to wipe out 'Desktops' of all other users of the PC.

The first thing that should be considered is that a normal user typically does not have access to desktop folders of other users because of NTFS file system permissions which avoids non Administrators from accessing other users profile. So the resulting script will have to run with administrative privileges. Even running the script as Administrator does guarantee the success because each user can explicitly deny access to his/her user profile files/folders even to Administrators.

The other thing is while it is mostly the case that the desktop directory of each user is placed in a folder named `Desktop` located in the `%USERPROFILE%` directory e.g. `C:\Users\John\Desktop` but this is not always the case. In fact the desktop directory of each user can defined to be located anywhere and placed in a folder other than `Desktop`.
This is the case for other special folders other than Desktop.

So the correct approach is to first retrieve a list of user profiles from registry and then for each user profile query the location of user's desktop.

```bat
:: WipeDesktops.cmd
:: This script should be runned as Administrator to be able to access and delete the 'Desktop' contents of other users.

@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: To turn TestMode off It is highly recommended that to invoke the script with "/TestMode:Off" switch rather than manually setting TestMode to 0
set "TestMode=1"
set "DeleteCommandConfirm=rd /s"
set "DeleteCommandUnsafe=rd /s /q"

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in ("%~1") do if /i "%%A"=="/TestMode" (
    if /i "%%B"=="Off" (set "TestMode=0") else set "TestMode=1"
)

set "DeleteCommand=%DeleteCommandConfirm%"
if %TestMode% NEQ 0 (
    echo Running in Test Mode
    set "DeleteCommand=echo %DeleteCommand%"
) else (
    set "DeleteCommand=2>nul %DeleteCommand%"
)

set "SID_Prefix=S-1-5-21-"
set "ProfileList=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
set "ShellFoldersBase=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"
set "ShellFolders=%ShellFoldersBase%\Shell Folders"
set "UserShellFolders=%ShellFoldersBase%\User Shell Folders"

for /F "delims=" %%K in ('reg query "%ProfileList%" /k /f "%SID_Prefix%"') do (
    set "ProfileKey=%%~K"
    set "ProfileKey=!ProfileKey:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\=HKLM\!"
    if "!ProfileKey!" NEQ "!ProfileKey:HKLM\=!" (
        set "ProfilePath="
        for /F "tokens=2*" %%A in ('reg query "!ProfileKey!" /v "ProfileImagePath" 2^>nul') do (
            set "ProfilePath=%%~B"
        )
        if defined ProfilePath if exist "!ProfilePath!\" (
            set "Desktop="
            set "SID=!ProfileKey:%ProfileList%\=!"
            for %%S in ("%UserShellFolders%", "%ShellFolders%") do (
                if not defined Desktop (
                    for /F "tokens=2*" %%A in ('reg query "HKU\!SID!\%%~S" /v "Desktop" 2^>nul') do (
                        set "Desktop=%%~B"
                    )
                    if defined Desktop (
                        REM %USERPROFILE% value is different for each user so it can not be expanded
                        for %%A in ("!ProfilePath!") do set "Desktop=!Desktop:%%USERPROFILE%%=%%~A!"
                        if not exist "!Desktop!\" set "Desktop="
                    )
                )
            )
            if not defined Desktop set "Desktop=!ProfilePath!\Desktop"
            REM Skip network paths
            if "!Desktop:~0,2!" NEQ "\\" if exist "!Desktop!\" (
                cd /d "!Desktop!" 2>nul && (
                    echo Removing 'Desktop' contents in !Desktop! ...

                    REM Since there is an open handle to the 'Desktop' folder, The contents of the folder will be removed but the folder itself remains.
                    %DeleteCommand% "!Desktop!"
                ) 
            )
        )
    )
)
```

For safety reasons it has 2 modes of operation:

- Test Mode (the default): In this mode it only shows the commands along with the path that it can delete but no actual deletion will be performed
- Normal Mode (invoke with `/TestMode:Off` switch) which will list and actually deletes the detected user desktops.

**How it works**

It first retrieves a list user profiles from registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` each of them located under a registry key with a name that is equal to the corresponding user SID beginning with `S-1-5-21-`

for each SID key it queries the value of `ProfileImagePath` to obtain the location of the user profile directory.

Then it queries the location of user's desktop from two registry locations in the listed order:

`HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

`HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`

and uses the value of `ProfileImagePath` to resolve the value of `%USERPROFILE%` variable for that user which is typically present in the special locations under the `User Shell Folders` key

Finally if the location of user's desktop can not be determined through registry then the default path of `%USEPROFILE%\Desktop` is assumed.

**What is missing?**

Shared user desktop is not covered, which is commonly located at `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop` or `%PUBLIC%\Desktop` depending on windows version.
But the definite location can be obtained from these registry keys:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`

So I'll leave it to you to do the rest and complete the missing part.