# Batch Script for Multiple Users on Shared Computer

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know very little about coding but I've cobbled together a cleaning batch.

I cannot figure out how to run it for every user on a shared computer.

What I have is as follows:

```
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local
rmdir /S /Q Temp
cd C:\
del C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.* /Q/F/S
del C:\Windows\Temp\*.* /Q/F/S
del C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items\*.* /Q
del "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ilk2mwjz.default\cache2\*.*"  /s /f /q /a
del "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cache\*.*" /s /f /q /a
del "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\*.*" /s /f /q /a
```

I had `for /d %%a in (C:\Users\*)` at the beginning, but that seems to break it.

Comment: if you want help, it makes sense to show the not-working code, not just the part that works.

Comment: Just FYI, `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local`=`%LocalAppData%`, `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp`=`%Temp%` and `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming`=`%AppData%`. You should never remove the `%Temp%` directory, instead if you `CD` into it before running the `RD` command it should remove its content. For your task, you'd also need to run the script 'As Administrator'. You should not choose to remove from every profile listed beneath `C:\Users` there are other ways of determining 'normal' local user profiles, the same goes for determining the unique `Firefox` profile directory names.

Comment: @Stephen

for /d %%a in (C:\Users\*)
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local
rmdir /S /Q Temp
cd C:\
del C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.* /Q/F/S
del C:\Windows\Temp\*.* /Q/F/S
del C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items\*.* /Q
del "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ilk2mwjz.default\cache2\*.*"  /s /f /q /a
del "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cache\*.*" /s /f /q /a
del "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\*.*" /s /f /q /a

This was the not working batch.

Comment: you are aware that `%username%` is the username of the currently active user and doesn't change? You want `%%a` instead.

Comment: @Compo I will make those changes. This batch will be run once in a while on shared computers. I can't go through every user and files as there are at least 15ish users per computer. Some users are on all, while others are one or half.

Comment: @Stephan so the command would be 

C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items*.* /Q del 
?

Comment: could work if you move the command (`del`)  to the front `:D`

Comment: @Stephan - This is what I have now

cd C:\

del /Q/F/S "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Temp\*"

del /Q/F/S "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*"

del /Q/F/S "C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.*"

del /Q/F/S "C:\Windows\Temp\*.*"

del /Q "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items\*.*"

del /Q/F/S "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cache\*.*"

del /Q/F/S "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\*.*"

Would you know if there is a wildcard for the firefox profile? Didn't realize it changed from user to user.

Comment: Some of the back slashes are not showing up for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearing you're trying to remove files from each user, you can simply use an `FOR` statement to `CD` to the correct directory the file exists in. Bellow is an example.

```
:search
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\desktop\*.ico" (
    set correctDir=%%G\desktop
    goto foundFile
)
goto :eof

:foundFile
cd "%correctDir%"
del /S *.ico
goto :search
```

The script above will remove all `.ico` files from each users desktop. It works by searching each desktop for any existing `.ico` files and the first result it will `CD` to it. The loop will return to the `FOR` statement until it finds no more `.ico`'s on users desktops. The basis of the code was taken from my original but similar response on the thread - [batch script to delete all icons from all users' desktops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326892/batch-script-to-delete-all-icons-from-all-users-desktops/51328103#51328103).

Using this method, we can do multiple files/folders for each user. **Be sure** to run this script as administrator as some locations require admin access to remove Objects!

```
@ECHO OFF

Rem These item's are not user specific so we can just remove them.
del C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.* /Q /F /S
del C:\Windows\Temp\*.* /Q /F /S

Echo Windows\Prefetch\*.* Was deleted for all users!
Echo Windows\Temp\*.* Was deleted for all users!
goto File1

Rem The following items will be removed from each users.
Rem First Object.
:File1
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*" (
    rem Here we need to CD one less layer to delete the folder.
    set "correctDir=%%G\AppData\Local"
    goto Found1
)
Echo Local\Temp\*.* Was deleted on all users!
goto File2

:Found1
cd "%correctDir%"
rmdir /S /Q Temp
goto File1

Rem Second object.
:File2
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items\*.*" (
    set "correctDir=%%G\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items"
    goto Found2
)
Echo Windows\Recent Items\*.* Was deleted on all users!
goto File3

:Found2
cd "%correctDir%"
del /Q *.*
goto File2

Rem Third object.
:File3
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ilk2mwjz.default\cache2\*.*" (
    set "correctDir=%%G\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ilk2mwjz.default\cache2"
    goto Found3
)
Echo ilk2mwjz.default\cache2\*.* Was deleted on all users!
goto File4

:Found3
cd "%correctDir%"
del /S /F /Q /A *.*
goto File3

Rem Forth object.
:File4
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cache\*.*" (
    set "correctDir=%%G\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cache"
    goto Found4
)
Echo Default\cache\*.* Was deleted on all users!
goto File5

:Found4
cd "%correctDir%"
del /S /F /Q /A *.*
goto File4

Rem Fifth object.
:File5
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\*.*" (
    set "correctDir=%%G\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC"
    goto Found5
)
Echo Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\*.* Was deleted on all users!
goto Completed

:Found5
cd "%correctDir%"
del /S /F /Q /A *.*
goto File5

Rem Finished Tasks.
:Completed
echo All Objects removed from users!
pause

goto :eof
```

For command basics,

- `FOR /D` iterates over all directories using the `%%G` variable.
- `%%~fG` expands to the full path to the directory in `%%G`.
- `IF EXIST` checks if a file exists.
- `CD` specifies that you want to change to the parent directory.
- `goto :eof` exits the script.

Comment: If I completely misread your question and this is not what you needed then my oligopolies. Hope this can at least help someone else in the future.

Comment: I was looking for the %%A command, since I did not know how to apply the script to all users; but I do like yours a lot more. The only issue is the Firefox cache part, the profile changes from user to user and it is random characters/numbers. I did not realize this until Compo pointed it out. It looks like **"\Profiles\*.*"** will do the trick.

You read it perfectly, I think I will use your script. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @ZakRyan Glad I could help! If this solved your issue please mark it as solved. This lets other know your question was completed and helps me in the process. Also, the same script can be used to find the missing profile name for firefox and "Skip" it. Furthermore, `%%A` and `%%G` are both the same when using `for` statements; either one can be used - They simply show the current result of the `for` loop.